How to edit a page in Wordpress that a user would need to sign in to view?
I have a Superio Theme installed which is a job board.  I am logged in as Admin so that I can edit my site, but the pages that a registered "Employer" would access I cannot edit because I am not logged in as a "Employer".
I have tried to register my Admin details as an Employer also, but it wouldnt allow that as the email was already used.  So, in essence, how can I gain access to a page that you would see if you were logged in, when I am editing it as an Admin?
I have a number of Users setup, with different access levels, but seems odd that I need to be registered as an Employer to see a page, but that level of access isnt enough to edit that page.
I am sure someone will have faced this before.  Thankyou

it's not a free theme then we cannot test it to try to correct this bug. you will have more help in asking the developer of this theme.

Thankyou @mmm, I have submitted a ticket to the developer.
